# Converting decimal dates to calendar dates?

Tags: decimal-expansion, calendar-computations

I have the decimal number **2005.067** which represents the date **January 25, 2005**. The math equation below shows how the decimal number is created **2005 + (25 - 0.5)/365**. I want to be able to grab **2005.067** and convert it back to **January 25, 2005**.

> **January 25, 2005 (Day 25) = 2005 + (25 - 0.5)/365 =2005.067**

I don't have that great of an understanding of math to be able to figure it out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiply the fractional part with $366$ (or $367$, if the year has $366$ days) and round it down. This gives the number of the day, for example the $37$th day. Then simply count which day it is. Note that the result cannot exceed $365$, if you multiply a fractional part with $366$. The answer below deals with correct rounding, also possible.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Peter the hint and answer below helped out a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $$((x-2005)\times365)+.5\\\text{or}\\((x-\text{year})\times365)+.5$$ to get what day of the year it is.  For example, 25 in this case.
$$\begin{align}((2005.067-2005)\times365)+.5&=0.067\times365+.5\\&\approx25\end{align}$$